# QGIS 3.22 Learning Module 2.2--layers scale

Tags: qgis

I'm really new to QGIS, and am trying to work through the learning modules. I'm at the very beginning of the modules, and am trying to load layers from the exercise data--but the layers seem to be at very different scales. My 'protected areas' layer, as the base layer, is much smaller and at a different scale than all the other layers I'm trying to add. I've been using the .shp files, but even if I try other file types, I'm still running into this problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to the module

Comment: What do you mean by scale? A layer is not "in a scale", it has an extent, do you mean that? A lot about your question is unclear: post a screenshot of what you have and link to the exercise, as mentioned by @BERA